# How to install MarcEdit

Tags: software-installation

I wish to install [MarcEdit](https://marcedit.reeset.net/downloads).

MarcEdit is a closed source app build with .NET that runs [over mono](https://www.mono-project.com/). Is usually used on libraries, where [MARC records](https://www.loc.gov/marc/) is a common format.

Comment: It is written on that site how to install it.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please take your time to follow that instructions. You'll notice they are wrong and incomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow this installation procedure

```sh
sudo apt install mono-runtime yaz zlibc libxml2 libxslt1-dev        # Dependencies
wget "https://marcedit.reeset.net/software/marcedit7/marcedit7.run" # Download MarcEdit 7

chmod u+x marcedit7.run                 # Make it executable
./marcedit7.run --target $HOME/marcedit # Unpackage it on preferred folder

cd $HOME/marcedit
./create_shortcut.sh # Generate shortcut (on ~/.local/share/applications), without using desktop-file-install.
sudo update-desktop-database
```

[image: screenshot]

#### Update 2022

- [`zlib`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=zlibc&searchon=names) was [removed from Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667148/zlibc-package-not-found) and derivatives. Also ibxml2.

#### Notes

- Keep in mind MarcEdit is a non-free software build with C#/Mono and is very buggy under Linux. Either way sadly doesn't exist an open source [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/marcedit/?license=opensource) (so far).
- On newer versions (7.3.11) I came across to [this issue](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/19986) (Mono 4.6.2, with 6.12.0.122 seems to work). You can report any bugs [here](http://marcedit.reeset.net/bug-report?version=MarcEdit7).

---

**Why this post**: I found this procedure much easier, straightforward and complete way for IT people working on libraries than the [instructions of the author](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfoSt0ll8S0). Moreover, this way works and the one shown by the [author site](https://marcedit.reeset.net/downloads) doesn't. Doesn't mention `chmod` the `.run` file, nor how to generate and move the shortcut to the appropriate location. Also, won't work without fixing the `–target` to `--target`, something probably newbies will miss.

Comment: What is the point of posting this?

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the reasons to the answer. I don't get why the downvotes.

Comment: I add to install this too:
sudo apt install libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil

Is there a way to open a MARC file with a double-click ?